# SQL conditional join with subselect

Tags: sql, database, aggregate

I do not understand why this code isn't working.  I have a join which needs a different join condition depending on the result of a subselect.

When the term date is null, I want this to come after the and operator:  and vs.term_date is null
When the term date is not null, I want the subquery below to come after the and operator.  I need to join on the max effective date:  vs.eff_date = (subquery)

I realize this code is messy, but I have to aggregate with a subselect since there are multiple rows coming back and I only want one.  (but open to other solutions)

```
select *
From loc
inner join VendorSite vs
    on loc.Record_Number = vs.SITE_NO
    and --conditional join
        case
            when        
            (
                case
                    when    --if term date is null i want this after "and"
                        (select top 1 TERM_DATE
                        from VendorSite vs2
                        where vs2.SITE_NO = vs.SITE_NO
                        order by TERM_DATE asc) is null
                    then 1
                    else 0  
                end 
            ) = 1
            then vs.term_date is null
            else --when term_date isn't null use max eff date
                vs.eff_date = 
                    (select max(eff_date) 
                    from VendorSite vs2
                    where vs2.SITE_NO = loc.Record_Number)
        end
```

Example:  From the below dataset, I would only want to see the row where term_date is null come back.

```
site_no eff_date                term_date
13588   2007-01-01 00:00:00.000 NULL
13588   2007-03-01 00:00:00.000 2007-11-09 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a database tag.  I can't imagine that nested `case` expressions are really needed in an `on` clause.

Comment: removing the nesting is fine but doesn't resolve the issue.  @GordonLinoff